# Zonal Statistics on discrete values in raster using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, zonal-statistics

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I am using Corine Land Cover raster data for Southern European Countries, this data gives discrete values to particular land uses (e.g. 1 = agricultural land, 2= Urban land-use etc.). I also have a polygon layer with the outlines of each country. I can get the total number of cells within each country from zonal statistics table in Arc toolbox, however I cannot get counts for each of the values of land use within each polygon. The goal is to determine the percentage of each country which is covered by each land-use category.

Is there any way in ArcGIS that I can achieve this?

Comment: You could use arcpy to iterate through feature geometry using a search cursor, perform "Tabulate Area", and write results to a master table.

Comment: Tabulate area tool will do the job

Comment: Furthermore, when using Tabulate Area tool, ensure the boundary polygons have a unique field to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to create an indicator grid of `0`s and `1`s, as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81035/how-to-calculate-custom-zonal-statistics).

You can then use `Count` to provide total number of raster cells in each polygon, and `Sum` to indicate how many cells are of a particular land use. The only issue being that you have to create an indicator grid for each land use type.