# QGIS equivalent to the ArcMap Zonal Statistics as Table

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, histogram

Is there a QGIS equivalent to the Arc: Spacial Analyst: Zonal: Zonal Statistics as Table?

Given the USDA Cropland Data Layer, Would like to count the pixels by type within a county.

Comment: from the Raster menu, Zonal Statistics...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `Zonal Statistics` will only give a summary of *all* cells within each polygon. To extract values for each land cover type (closer to Arc's Zonal Statistics as Table) you can create an indicator grid for each land cover type as shown in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81035/how-to-calculate-custom-zonal-statistics)

**Edit**

As of QGIS 3.2 there is a [Zonal Histogram tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-histogram-32) which should perform this automatically.