# Tabulate area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, tabulate

Does anyone know if there exists in QGIS any tool similar to "Tabulate Area" of ArcGIS to be able to calculate what percentage of values of a raster for each polygon?

So far I am using pktools, pkextract but the time it takes to process is huge, not acceptable for very large surfaces.

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/is-there-a-tabulate-area-function-in-qgis

Comment: can you be more explicit as to what you mean by large surfaces (i.e. number of pixels and polygons)? I use pkextract on very large datasets without any trouble.

Comment: I refer to large raster, for example watersheds. I usually use pkextract to calculate what percentage of soil types there are in several basins of a hydrographic basin. This operation is almost instantaneous using tabulate area in Arcgis but using pkextract can last hours.
I'm afraid something should not be doing well

Answer (score 2):

[Zonal Histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-histogram) (QGIS 3.4) has worked successfully for me to derive land cover totals (from a TIF) per county (held as shapefile).

I was searching for an answer to this exact same question. However, a [different question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233012/qgis-equivalent-to-the-arcmap-zonal-statistics-as-table/314008#314008) (about an equivalent for Zonal Statistics) was where I found this information. To me, Zonal Histogram seems to be a more direct equivalent to Tabulate Area than to Zonal Statistics, so I am posting it here to make the answer more easily searchable.

It calculates a total, not a percentage as per the original question, but it at least makes a percentage possible to calculate.