# Statistical difference in DEM-height compared to a specific point(feature)

Tags: qgis, dem, zonal-statistics, slope, comparison

Recently I've been struggling when trying to compare surrounding points of a DEM to a specific one (a feature in my case. A castle to be precise). I want to find out how steep a slope in an area around the castle is, compared to the castle/point itself.

I've tried with a buffer for the area and using zonal statistics afterwards, but this has proven to be unsatisfying for my research question.

Anyone got a smart approach for this?

Comment: A few questions: 1. What about the buffer and zonal stats (which stat?) results was unsatisfying? And was your buffer area a donut so as not to include the castle with the surrounding area? 2. Which software are you using?

Comment: 1. the zonal statistics only give me values, but these can't be connected to the feature point. no, it was a circle, as I wanted to know the correlation between the castle and surrounding raster cells of the DEM.
2. using QGIS 3.16

Comment: It sounds like you want something like ArcGIS's Zonal Statistics as Table. This post goes into some QGIS options: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233012/qgis-equivalent-to-the-arcmap-zonal-statistics-as-table. You might also want to consider how big your specific locations and surrounding areas are compared to the pixel size of your DEM.

Comment: If you use zonal statistics, you get values for each buffer, so by itself they are connected to the belonging points because the buffers derive from the points. Use `Join attributes by location (summary)` to add the zonal statistics results to the original point layer. So I still don't understand what is unsatifying for you. Please describe in detail what exactly you want to get - otherwise, it's dificult to give advice.