# Zonal statistics per raster category in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, zonal-statistics, histogram

I have a raster layer of land use and a vector layer of areas of interest.

I would like to calculate for each polygon (areas of interest) the proportion or number of cells of the raster, for each category. I would like to get a table of areas in rows, raster categories in columns and the number/proportion of cell for each combination.

I'm sure there is an easy way to do that but I couldn't find it. All I got was global statistics through Zonal Stats but I couldn't calculate per category.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

As of QGIS 3.2, there is the [Zonal Histogram tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-histogram) which should perform this automatically, saving the need to create multiple indicator grids (see original answer).

---

**Original answer:**

I had a very similar situation, and came across https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/81047/16141

Essentially, you have to create an indicator grid of `0`s and `1`s for each of your land use types. And then use a combination of `Count` and `Sum` from the `Zonal Statistics` plugin. `Count` will give total number of raster cells in each polygon, and `Sum` will give number of cells = `1`. You can then determine proportion of cover within each polygon. Maybe a bit cumbersome if you have a lot of land use types, but straightforward.

---

Comment: The `Zonal Histogram` is a perfect tool in QGIS 3.x for zonal analysis.